# Property and Synthesize in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to learn Cocoa and wanted to develop a very simple game that I had played in my youth. It was originally created in MS Basic. Please note I'm very new to Cocoa and objective c

I have create and object called Defaults. It stores three integer variables, planets, fighters and players.

On the front end, I have three drop down boxes with various defaulted values.

I wanted to understand KVC as well as how to set values but I get the following warning...

"Incompatible integer to pointer sending 'int' to parameter of type 'int *'

[NEW CODE]

**DEFAULTS.H**

#import 
   #import

```
@interface Defaults : NSObject {

int fighters;
int planets;
int players;

}

@property (assign) int fighters;
@property (assign) int planets;
@property (assign) int players;

@end
```

Here is an excerpt of the implementation in my controller:

```
#import "DefaultsController.h"
#import "Defaults.h"
```

@implementation DefaultsController

```
- (id)init
{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code here
 Defaults *theDefaults = [[Defaults alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Planets: %@",[theDefaults valueForKey:(@"planets")]);
}
return self;
```

}

```
-(void)dealloc
{ 
[super dealloc];
[Defaults release]; 
}

-(void) awakeFromNib{

}

-(IBAction) addPlanets:(id)sender{

[theDefaults setValue:[planetsButton titleOfSelectedItem] forKey:@"planets"];
[theDefaults setPlanets:[[planetsButton titleOfSelectedItem] intValue]];
theDefaults.planets = [[planetsButton titleOfSelectedItem] intValue];
NSLog(@"Planets: %i", theDefaults.planets);
NSLog(@"%@", [planetsButton titleOfSelectedItem]);
NSLog(@"%i", [[planetsButton titleOfSelectedItem] intValue]);

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

You've declared your properties to be integer pointers, but then you're attempting to set them to integer values, not integer pointer values.  Remove the asterisks in "int *fighters", etc, to change them to integers.

Pointers are one of the most fundamental and challenging concepts of C-based languages (including Objective-C), and if you aren't clear on the distinction I drew above I suggest you look for some careful explanations of how they work.

**Update**:

Another issue I see here, which may relate to your question below, is that you're doing some funny things with your logging statements.  When you put `%@` in a formatting string, you're telling NSLog that you want it to replace that with an Objective-C **object**.  But an int is not an object; it's just a basic C type.  Then, you're using key-value coding to retrieve your property value, which is further confusing the issue, because key-value coding is also intended to work with Objective-C objects.  Replace that line with the following:

```
NSLog(@"Planets: %i", theDefaults.planets);
```

and I think you'll get something more in line with what you're expecting.  `%i` tells NSLog that you have an integer value to print, and `theDefaults.planets` (or the equivalent `[theDefaults planets]`) will return the value of the planets property, whether it's an object or not.

Comment: What about the value from the popupbutton. I think this is string. do I have to cast this to INT? Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: If you're trying to read the label of the button and use it as a number, you have to invoke a function that will interpret a string as a number -- this is different than a cast.  `-intValue` will do that for you.

Comment: I just changed all the pointer types to values. That got rid of the problem but I can't set the value. Is there something special I need to do to get the value from the drop down to int?

Comment: @Axwack: As Seamus suggested, you need to send the string `intValue`.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry to be dense. I thought that was doing it with this line:  [theDefaults setPlanets:[[planetsButton titleOfSelectedItem] intValue]];

Comment: That is what that line does.  I'm afraid I don't understand the question.  What do you mean when you say "I can't set the value"?

Comment: Thank you Seamus. I changed the NSLog line and get a better result. However, when I make a selection on the popupbutton (1,5,7 are the titles). It doesn't set the planets value in the Defaults class. It comes out with zero still.

Comment: What do you see when you `NSLog(@"%@", [planetsButton titleOfSelectedItem])`?

Comment: For that it's 7 for theDefaults.planets it's 0

Comment: Did you remember to `@synthesize planets` in your Defaults.m file?  What do you see if you `NSLog(@"%i", [[planetsButton titleOfSelectedItem] intValue])`?

Comment: I get 7 when I select 7...but it doesn't set the planets. Yes..I did @synthesize planets in the Defaults.m

Comment: I don't think we can solve this without seeing your updated code.

Comment: Okay, the issue is that you're not storing your instance of your Defaults object in your DefaultsController object: you just created it in `-init` and let it go out of scope.  If you have an ivar called theDefaults, it's set to nil, which explains why none of your messages to it are having any effect.  In init, change `Defaults *theDefaults` to `self.theDefaults` (and autorelease the object you created, if `theDefaults` is a retain property).